# How to set a rule for the order of minor-mode-map-alist

Tags: minor-mode

Suppose we have 3 mode, one such rule is like key map for mode 1 should always come before mode 2, and mode 3 should always come before mode 1, finally mode 3 should always come before other minor mode. Is there a easy way to do it? How is the order determined in emacs? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a quick point on posting norms: there's no need to add a "thank you" to the end of your post.  (And actually, [it's preferable not to add it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).)

Comment: You might need to manually doctor the `minor-mode-map-alist` [similar to what I need to do for `minor-mode-alist`](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/7cf37059ff2e406470f64fe730d8a0436f44d7db/setup-files/setup-misc.el#L288-L292).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a minor mode *MY-MINOR-MODE*, you can make the bindings of that mode override ALL others (major and minor modes) by advising `load` as below:

```el
(defadvice load (after give-my-keybindings-priority)
  "Try to ensure that my keybindings always have priority."
  (when (not (eq (car (car minor-mode-map-alist)) 'MY-MINOR-MODE))
      (let ((mykeys (assq 'MY-MINOR-MODE minor-mode-map-alist)))
        (assq-delete-all 'MY-MINOR-MODE minor-mode-map-alist)
        (add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist mykeys))))
(ad-activate 'load)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5340797/1219634)

---

So if you want *MINOR-MODE-A* at the highest priority followed by *MINOR-MODE-B*, followed by *MINOR-MODE-C*, you would do:

```el
(defadvice load (after give-my-keybindings-priority)
  "Try to ensure that the keymap priorities are in the following order:
 MINOR-MODE-A > MINOR-MODE-B > MINOR-MODE-C."
  (when (not (eq (car (car minor-mode-map-alist)) 'MINOR-MODE-C))
    (let ((mykeys (assq 'MINOR-MODE-C minor-mode-map-alist)))
      (assq-delete-all 'MINOR-MODE-C minor-mode-map-alist)
      (add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist mykeys)))

  (when (not (eq (car (car minor-mode-map-alist)) 'MINOR-MODE-B))
    (let ((mykeys (assq 'MINOR-MODE-B minor-mode-map-alist)))
      (assq-delete-all 'MINOR-MODE-B minor-mode-map-alist)
      (add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist mykeys)))

  ;; `when' block for the highest priority minor mode put at the very last 
  (when (not (eq (car (car minor-mode-map-alist)) 'MINOR-MODE-A))
    (let ((mykeys (assq 'MINOR-MODE-A minor-mode-map-alist)))
      (assq-delete-all 'MINOR-MODE-A minor-mode-map-alist)
      (add-to-list 'minor-mode-map-alist mykeys))))
(ad-activate 'load)
```