# What determines key bindings in the Magit commit window?

Tags: key-bindings, magit

I'm a happy Magit user, and at commit time, I am accustomed to editing a commit message and then finishing the edit with `C-c C-c`.  But sometimes that key sequence winds up bound to the `compile` function, as indeed my emacs init file contains the line

```
(global-set-key "\C-c\C-c" 'compile)
```

My init file also sets that key locally in a number of modes including `c-mode`, `sml-mode`, `lua-mode`, and so on.  *However*, none of those modes is displayed on the mode line in the commit-edit window.  And when emacs is working correctly, `C-c C-c` finishes the edit and returns to git as expected.  However, every so often it gets wacky and insists on being bound to `compile`.

Following a trail of emacs lisp leads a very short distance to where Magit invokes git with `$EMACSCLIENT` set appropriately.  Beyond that point I have been unable to diagnose how that buffer is created or where its keybindings are determined.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to **set the keybindings in the commit-message edit buffer so that `C-c C-c` terminates the edit and returns control to git.**   At the moment, the only way I can do this is to exit emacs and start over.  That workaround doesn't last long, and it grows tiresome.

I would welcome answers to any or all of the following questions:

1. Where are the keybindings set for that window?
2. What function is `C-c C-c` bound to by default?
3. Is there a mode or other hook where I can just reach in with a hammer and bind `C-c C-c` to the right function?

---

Addendum: the buffer's major mode is `text-mode`. Here is the response to `C-h v major-mode RET`:

```
Its value is text-mode
Original value was fundamental-mode
Local in buffer COMMIT_EDITMSG; global value is fundamental-mode
```

Comment: [How can I find out in which keymap a key is bound?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/653/5296) might help. I think the final answer will involve manipulating `minor-mode-map-alist` as in [How to set a rule for the order of minor-mode-map-alist](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13447/5296)

Comment: What major mode is the Git commit buffer in (`C-h v major-mode RET`)?

Comment: @Gilles the major mode is `text-mode`.  I've updated the question.

Comment: @npostavs thanks for your comment which got me on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to commenters, this is what I was able to learn:

1. Some keybindings were set by an overeager `after-change-major-mode-hook`, which doubtless was a workaround for a legacy bug somewhere.  (The question of where the *correct* keybinding is set remains unanswered.)
2. The function bound by default is `with-editor-finish`, which I eventually discovered by starting with `emacs -q`
3. I reached in with the hammer of `after-change-major-mode-hook`, or rather, I made the hammer that I already found there hit with a little less force.

Of the resources named in the comments, [How can I find out in which keymap a key is bound?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-i-find-out-in-which-keymap-a-key-is-bound) provided no useful information—lots of things were set to `nil`.   But looking at the major and minor modes were most excellent hints!

Comment: `locate-key-binding` from the linked question got me `Minor-mode: with-editor-mode: with-editor-finish` (in addition to the `nil`s), but that's starting from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: "The question of where the correct keybinding is set remains unanswered." - [with-editor.el:324](https://github.com/magit/with-editor/blob/v2.5.0/with-editor.el#L324)