# How to prioritize key bindings between modes?

Tags: key-bindings

I have two modes that bind a key. How can I choose which one should get to do its thing?

I'm asking generally but currently the situation is that when I'm in a certain mode, I want to use its bindings (which are currently shadowed by another mode).

I even tried to add a hook that `local-set-key`s at the end of my init file but that doesn't work, it gets shadowed too.

Comment: Most simply, minor mode keymaps take precedence over the local (major mode, usually) keymap, which takes precedence over the global keymap. Minor mode keymap precedence is based on the order of `minor-mode-map-alist` at any given time (you can use `after-load-functions` to programatically massage this as new libraries are loaded). However there are more (and more complex) levels of keymap than this. You should update your question with precise details of what you are doing. Include the relevant elisp.

Comment: See the Elisp manual, node [Active Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html).

Comment: minor-mode keymaps always take precedence over the major mode and your local-keymap (which is usually a modified copy of the major-mode map). However, the problem you've run into is that multiple minor-modes can conflict with each other, and there's no built-in way to force one to have priority over another. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13447/how-to-set-a-rule-for-the-order-of-minor-mode-map-alist for a workaround

Comment: "mode" is too vague to be able to answer.  Minor mode?  Major mode?  Just tell us which modes you're thinking of.